# Tag for User Interface

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

I would like to propose a tag for "User Interface".

While interfacing with a digital equipment user / developer has following UI components:

1. Buttons
2. Potentiometer
3. LCD (txt and graphics)
4. LEDs
5. Rotary Encoder

and many more.

Is it OK to create a new tag for UI (Useer Interface)?

If not approved, what is the best tag for "User Interface" questions?

Comment: I don't see the point in limiting UI to digital equipment.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't add a "UI" tag. What I would use:

- for inputs: "buttons", "sensors", ...
- for outputs: "actuators", "LCD", ...

I don't think every component needs a separate tag, i.c. a potentiometer. Tags must remain somewhat generic. If you are too specific with your tags we'll end up with 100000 of them in no time, each only used 2 or 3 times.